# How to find specific parameters in an equation using calculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to understand how parameters "a" and "b" are found (eqs. 2.31 and 2.32 in Fig 3) according to the explanation below (see the figures).

[Fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uz0W.png)

[Fig 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdUwn.png)

[Fig 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thL9W.png)

I tried to separate the a or b in the second differential and then to use integrations in order to reach the original function but obviously that wasn't the right method. These equations come from "Thermodynamics in Mineral Sciences" by Ladislav Cemic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to see the mathematics behind finding the "a" and "b". What is the algebraic manipulation of the equations in the figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the second equality in (2.29) to obtain

$
a=\frac{V_c^3}{2}\,\frac{RT_c}{(V_c-b)^2}~(*)
$

Take this value of $a$ and substitute it in the second equality in (2.30). Rearrange for $b$. You end up with $b=V_c/3$, which is the result quoted in (2.32). If you now substitute $b=V_c/3$ into $(*)$ above, you find the value of $a$ in (2.31).

Hope this helps!

Comment: You really helped me to understand it! Thank you so much! All the best :)

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help!